# Is Pylon supply positive only

Tags: electricity

Is the supply above our heads , in the pylon wires, positive only? If so 
where does the negative supply begin and end?

Answer (score 2):

Typical electrical transmission is done with AC voltages, so there is no "positive" and "negative" wire- each wire varies over time from positive to zero to negative and back again.

In most places, if you look at a high voltage electricity pylon, you may notice that it carries three wires (or some multiple of three). Each of these carries an AC signal, each out of phase from the others by $120^\circ$. If a negative or positive DC voltage is required, a three-phase rectifier can easily produce either.

This is called [three-phase electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power), and it allows for greater power transport using less wire than using the simpler system of just having one signal wire and one neutral wire.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical transmission can be by using ac but sometimes dc.

[The method which is most favoured is ac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power_transmission) because one can then step up the voltage at the generating station end and then step down the voltage at the consumer end using transformers (which only work with ac) and this will reduce the power loss in transmission.

The quoted transmitted voltage, say $500 \, \rm kV$ is the root mean square voltage (rms) with the actual voltage measured relative to a single "common return cable", which is near earth potential, ranging from  a positive peak of $+500\sqrt 2 = +700 \,\rm kV$ to a negative peak of $-700 \,\rm kV$.

The voltages for a domestic consumer are much smaller, eg the voltage of the live wire might be $110 \, \rm V$ rms which is approximately $\pm 156\, \rm V$ peak  relative to the voltage of the neutral wire which again is very near earth potential.

Sometimes [high voltage direct current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current) (HVDC) is used for long distance transmission of electrical power one of the reasons being that for a given amount of electrical power being transmitted the dc voltage will be lower than the peak ac voltage.
In such a HVDC transmission system the quoted voltage is the potential difference between the two conductors transmitting the electrical power.

This picture taken at night illustrates one of the problems with transmitting electrical power at high voltages.

[image]

The air is glowing because it is no longer a good insulator in the vicinity of the transmission lines and the corona discharge (violet colour) is the reason for the hissing that you hear near electricity pylons and overhead transmission lines.
The higher the voltage the more likely is corona discharge to happen.